# sklearn classifier get ValueError: bad input shape (3529, 12)

Tags: python, svm

I have a json file that file have preprocess data at the same time that data is also change vector.then how to train the data using SVM classification method

Vector is one name of the column
another one is values, values have genres of vector column

```
import pickle
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

stopwords=set(stopwords.words("english"))
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
snow=SnowballStemmer("english")

tvec = pickle.load(open("dataPackage/tfidf.pickle", 'rb'))
data=pd.read_json("dataPackage/finalData.json",orient = 'split')
inputLen = len(data["Vector"].iloc[0])

X = list(data["Vector"])
y = list(data.drop(["Vector"],axis = 1).values)

np.shape(X)
np.shape(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(X), np.array(y), test_size=0.3,random_state=109)

model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```